# Cuda L2 transfer overhead

Tags: cuda, disassembly, nsight, ldg

I have a kernel to test rendering points with `atomicMin`. The test setup has a tons of points in an idea case memory layout. Two buffers, one `uint32` for clusters of 256x `uint32`.

```
namespace Point
{
struct PackedBitfield
{
    glm::uint32_t x : 6;
    glm::uint32_t y : 6;
    glm::uint32_t z : 6;
    glm::uint32_t nx : 4;
    glm::uint32_t ny : 4;
    glm::uint32_t nz : 4;
    glm::uint32_t unused : 2;
};

union __align__(4) Packed
{
    glm::uint32_t bits;
    PackedBitfield field;
};

struct ClusterPositionBitfield
{
    glm::uint32_t x : 10;
    glm::uint32_t y : 10;
    glm::uint32_t z : 10;
    glm::uint32_t w : 2;
};

union ClusterPosition
{
    glm::uint32_t bits;
    ClusterPositionBitfield field;
};
}

//
// launch with blockSize=(256, 1, 1) and grid=(numberOfClusters, 1, 1)
//
extern "C" __global__ void pointsRenderKernel(mat4 u_mvp,
                    ivec2 u_resolution,
                    uint64_t* rasterBuffer,
                    Point::Packed* points, 
                    Point::ClusterPosition* clusterPosition)
{
// extract and compute world position
const Point::ClusterPosition cPosition(clusterPosition[blockIdx.x]);
const Point::Packed point(points[blockIdx.x*256 + threadIdx.x]);

...use points and write to buffer...

}
```

The resulting SASS looks like this:

[image]

Have a look at the memory profiler output: The L2 transfer overhead from the `Point::Packed*` buffer read is **3.0**. **Why is that?** The memory should be perfectly aligned and sequential. Also why is this automatically generating `LDG`(compute_50, sm_50)? I don't need this cached.

Comment: For read-only data, `LDG` uses the load path that is generally the most efficient, so the CUDA toolchain prefers to use that.

Comment: For those of us without that profiler (it's a Windows version I presume?)  can you mention what units is the overhead given in?

Comment: @einpoklum - overhead is multiple of memory transactions required to fetch the data. the profiler exist in Linux as well (except Eclipse based I believe).

Comment: @njuffa- it was not my question what sort of instruction the compiler generates.

Comment: We don't see the whole code, only `...use points and write to buffer...`, and only the first 10.8 lines of the assembly. You've shown only what you think is relevant, which apparently leads nowhere. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tooltip for *L2 Transfer Overhead*, it says that it measures "the number of bytes actually transferred between L1 and L2 for each requested byte in L1", and it also says that "lower is better".

In my case, the L2 Transfer Overhead for reading `Point::Packed` is `1.0`.

[image]

**TEST CODE**

```
namespace Point
{
    struct PackedBitfield
    {
        uint32_t x : 6;
        uint32_t y : 6;
        uint32_t z : 6;
        uint32_t nx : 4;
        uint32_t ny : 4;
        uint32_t nz : 4;
        uint32_t unused : 2;
    };

    union __align__(4) Packed
    {
        uint32_t bits;
        PackedBitfield field;
    };

    struct ClusterPositionBitfield
    {
        uint32_t x : 10;
        uint32_t y : 10;
        uint32_t z : 10;
        uint32_t w : 2;
    };

    union ClusterPosition
    {
        uint32_t bits;
        ClusterPositionBitfield field;
    };
}

__global__ void pointsRenderKernel(Point::Packed* points, Point::ClusterPosition* clusterPosition)
{
    int t_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    clusterPosition[blockIdx.x + blockDim.x] = clusterPosition[blockIdx.x];
    points[t_id + blockDim.x * gridDim.x] = points[t_id];
}

void main()
{
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numberOfClusters = 256;

    std::cout << sizeof(Point::Packed) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(Point::ClusterPosition) << std::endl;

    Point::Packed *d_points;
    cudaMalloc(&d_points, sizeof(Point::Packed) * numberOfClusters * blockSize * 2);

    Point::ClusterPosition *d_clusterPositions;
    cudaMalloc(&d_points, sizeof(Point::ClusterPosition) * numberOfClusters * 2);

    pointsRenderKernel<<<numberOfClusters, blockSize>>>(d_points, d_clusterPositions);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I had some other problems with Nsight before when I used the latest driver. I downgraded the driver to the version shipped with the default CUDA 8.0.61 installer(downloaded from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)) and it fixed the issue. The version shipped with the installer is 376.51. Tested on Windows 10 64-bit and Visual Studio 2015, Nsight version is 5.2 and my graphics card is cc6.1.

This is my full compiler command:

> nvcc.exe -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=\"sm_61,compute_61\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2015 -Xcompiler "/wd 4819" -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include" -lineinfo --keep-dir x64\Release -maxrregcount=0 --machine 64 --compile -cudart static -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DNDEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /FS /Zi /MD " -o x64\Release\kernel.cu.obj kernel.cu"

---

**UPDATE 2**

I get same result when I compile with `sm_50,compute_50` option: `1.0` for L2 Transfer Overhead.

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time and trying this out actually. I guess for both questions and answers to be acceptable, we'd both need to post the exact compiler flags used.

Comment: @FHoenig I also had some problems with Nsight before, and downgrading the NVIDIA graphics driver fixed the issue, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: do you get the same results with compute 5.0 / sm 5.0 ?

Comment: @FHoenig Yes, the value of L2 Transfer Overhead is `1.0`, also, when compiled with compute_50,sm_50.

Comment: While not really a direct answer, I am assuming this was a measurement error on an older version of Nsight.